# Suche ab/zum/nach?

Tags: word-usage, difference, word-choice, preposition

I'm writing a job application and I have a problem with a sentence.

I want to say that I'm currently waiting for my final grade, that my job contract is ending in August and that I need a new job then

> Momentan warte ich auf die Benotung meiner Masterarbeit und suche zu meinem Vertragsende in August nach einer neuen Tätigkeit...

or is it better to write:

> ...ab meinem Vertragende....

or

> ...nach meinem Vertragsende...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> … suche *zu* meinem Vertragsende …

The preposition *zu* is correct here. The phrase *zu einem gewissen Zeitpunkt* is used to say that something that you are looking for starts *at a certain point in time*, in your example, when the contract ends.

> … suche *ab / nach* meinem Vertragsende …

The prepositions *ab* and *nach* are actually *not* correct here. This phrase does *not* mean that you are (currently) looking for something that starts when the contract ends, but that the search itself starts when the contract ends. You can see this more easily by changing the word order:

> Ich suche nach meinem Vertragsende nach irgendwas …
>   
>   <sub>→ When will you look for something? When the contract ends.</sub>

Therefore, except for the preposition *in*, which should be *im*, your sentence is correct:

> Momentan warte ich auf die Benotung meiner Masterarbeit und suche *zu* meinem Vertragsende <s>in</s>im August nach einer neuen Tätigkeit …

Comment: Just wanted to write an answer to say just that. You were faster. ;)

Comment: `This phrase does not mean that you are (currently) looking for something that starts with the end of the contract, but that the search itself starts when the contract ends.` This is exactly what bothered me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this website: https://www.thegermanz.com/zu-nach-in-most-efficient-preposition-german/.
I think you will find it very useful.